# QList proper way of using it

Tags: c++, qt

I want to poppulate a QList with QLabel Objects, so i've created a List of QLabel Objects.

```
QLabel *myLabel;    
QList<QLabel> *thumbNails;
```

but as QList awaits a const QLabel &, how can i **append** to the Qlist in the right ways, should i use a const_cast ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely you put your `*` in a wrong place, which made `thumbNails` a pointer to a `QList`.
You should store pointers to `QLabel` inside your list. Try this: `QList<QLabel*> thumbNails;`